# Xcode 8 sets frame size differently. How do I find more details?

Tags: uikit, xcode8

In several places in my application I get zero frame sizes where I used to get a frame. This impacted me especially when creating round objects by doing a cornerRadius of `size/2`.

For example, in Xcode 7 this worked fine:

```
class AvatarUIButton: UIButton {
  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    layer.masksToBounds = true
    layer.cornerRadius = bounds.size.width / 2
  }
}
```

But now in Xcode 8 I have to do this:

```
class AvatarUIButton: UIButton {
  override var bounds: CGRect { didSet {
    layer.cornerRadius = bounds.size.width / 2
  }}

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
  }
}
```

In this example, the change is arguably better/more obvious. I have another situation that is much less isolated involving a 0 frame on TableHeaderView that is only for xcode 8.

I'm looking for release notes, mailing list discussion, or similar that discusses a change in ordering of frame size determination so I can figure out what changed and how I can fix it.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. It's an AutoLayout issue. In my case, frames are logging as (0, 0, 1000, 1000). Setting the corner radius to a fixed amount (not calculated) makes the view reappear again. Without using AutoLayout the problem doesn't exist.

Comment: I had a similar issue, with a subview in a custom table cell. The subview had constraints for position and size. _Before_ the cell was displayed the frame for this subview was {(0,0),(1000,1000)}. Custom drawing based on this frame was clearly not working. I found, while debugging AND inspecting the views, that only after the view was rendered on screen was the frame correct. My solution was to add `[cell layoutIfNeeded]` right after dequeuing the cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. It solved the problem for me and I was able to continue to calculate corner radius elsewhere.

Comment: Learned: yes, frames have 1000 or zero size in `viewWillAppear` now (depending on which xcode beta you have). But in `viewWillAppear` you can call `view.layoutIfNeeded()` to size your frames correctly.

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode 8, Apple say :

> Xcode 8 removes the ability to configure views without constraints
>   with frame varying per size class. Views without constraints may look
>   different after compiling with Xcode 8 when switching size classes at
>   runtime. Going forward, use constraints and autoresizing masks with
>   the device bar to achieve the desired layout. (25894544)

In previous versions of Xcode, we used to define the design on the ViewDidLoad. But here, the different elements were not created (and constraints too), so the view was created with the size in the Storyboard.

Now, in Xcode 8, we cannot do it anymore. We need to have constraints because the frame is not initialize (that's why some of you have these values for the frame size :  0, 0, 1000, 1000). For example, make it in the ViewDidAppear and it will work fine. But, you will see at first your button without corner radius few times.

So, what you can do is to use this function (here in Objective C) (where you want, even in the loading function) :

```
[self performSelector:@selector(setCornerToMyButton) withObject:NULL afterDelay:0];
```

You can pu the delay you want, but even with 0 it works.

And change your radius in this function like this for example :

```
- (void) setCornerToMyButton {
    //Do what you want... 
    layer.masksToBounds = true
    layer.cornerRadius = bounds.size.width / 2
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I don't size in `viewDidLoad`, I don't think that guarantees frame sizes. I do use `viewWillAppear`, any insight on that? I thought frames would be sized by then (not `viewDidLoad`), but they are not in xcode 8. Doing sizing on `viewDidAppear` causes layout shifting as you note, so that's not acceptable. Using a delay seems incorrect/hacky, though I'll trust you that it works. I think the platform should have a "ready to lay out" event. I thought that was `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: If you want to force update in the next frame, just use `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {})` instead of `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`. I think `performSelector` is pretty silly, especially in swift.

Answer (score 2):

in your case just call :

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
    layer.masksToBounds = true
    layer.cornerRadius = bounds.size.width / 2
}
```

for a UIViewController just call view.layoutIfNeed() right after super.viewDidLoad(),it ll work like a charm;
i dont know what s the cause of this problem (if it s a problem) either way it seems that loading the view doesnt "layout" the view anymore neither using autoresize or autolayout for that matter , so like i said for the time being you can use this solution till we get a better understanding about what changed exactly
also for custom classes (custom button for exemple) you can override layoutSubviews() or layoutIfNeeded() , there you ll find the frame/layout you are looking for and apply whatever changes you want

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer just now

```
[super viewDidLoad];
[self.myNeedFrameView layoutIfNeeded];
```

Comment: Could you explain where that code gets added in relation to the original question. If possible, even 'why' it fixes the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)

Comment: I understand the answer, but it doesn't apply to this exact question. Since this shows a UIView, there is no `viewDidLoad` hook. @DanielBarbarian is correct that this problem applies to View Controllers as well though, and that this is a fix in that case.